# How to run a callback function on a jQuery trigger("click")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, callback

I need to trigger a custom event in the callback of a `trigger` call, but I can't get it to work.

I tried this:

```
var $input = $( ".ui-popup-container" ).find( "input" ).eq(2);

function runtests () {
    console.log("clicked the input");
};
$input.trigger('click', runtests());
```

and this:

```
var $input = $( ".ui-popup-container" ).find( "input" ).eq(2);
$input.trigger('click', function(){
    console.log("clicked the input");
}
```

Neither of which works.

**Question:**
How do I get a callback function to run when I'm triggering a click on an element?

Comment: Why are you adding undefined as second parameter to trigger ? What's that second parameter supposed to do ? Are you confusing trigger and bind ?

Comment: That's my attempt at a callback function... I also tried wrapping it in `[]` as per [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), but also does not work

Comment: `.trigger` does not accept any callbacks. `$input.trigger('click')` triggers the `click` event on the `$input` elements, i.e. it will execute the `click` event handlers bound to those elements. It looks like you have bind `runtest` to `$input`, but  I'm not sure what your want exactly.

Comment: But how is this callback supposed to be used ?

Comment: @FelixKling: I need to click the input and after it has executed it's own handlers, I need to run a set of qunit tests (to check whether the input did what it should)

Comment: Event handlers execute in the order they are bound to the element. So if you bind your `qunit` callback to the elements *after* the "normal" event handlers, it should work fine. *edit:* But try dystroy's solution first, that would be the simplest.

Comment: ok. Trying. Thanks so far.

Comment: This might help you [call back for .trigger()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246409/callback-for-trigger-function)

Comment: @dystroy sorry i was editing my answer...you are so quick to judge...

Comment: Btw, how to handle such situations with QUnit is described on their website: http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#testing-user-actions. Looks like you don't need to bind an event handler.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you call `trigger`, the bound event handler is immediately executed, so you don't need any callback. Just use

```
$input.trigger('click');
runtests();
```

Comment: +1 That should work fine, according to the docs: http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#testing-user-actions.

Comment: @frequent, you were getting callbacks and handlers confused, of course. If there's no asynchronous activity associated with the action, it's a handler that you *trigger*, whereas if there is asynchronous activity, you assign a *callback* to handle it's response when it occurs (or by status).

Comment: This does not work for me. I get a race condition unless I use setTimeout on the runtests() function in the example.

Comment: this doesn't work when you have a long js code in the second part of the code and at end an ajax call. only solution which is a ugly one but settimeout seems to work

Answer (score 27):

Yes - It is true that trigger doesn't take callback but we can pass callback as parameter.

```
//.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )

$("#element").bind("customCall", function(e, callback){
   callback();
}
var callback = function(){alert("Hello");}
$("#element").trigger("customCall",[callback]);
```

Hope this will helps

Comment: If you're already familiar with the convention for assigning callback functions when defining a bound event for a DOM element, this answer actually tells you how you could actually pass a dynamic callback function at the time that the event is triggered. That makes it one of the most valuable answers on this page, to me.

Comment: Agree with @tobylaroni. Not sure why this was not the accepted answer! Probably the question was specific to 'trigger' than a custom call.

Comment: Read more about [`.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters).

Answer (score 12):

First you need to bind the click event and then you can trigger the click event.

```
$input.bind('click', function() {

     console.log("clicked the input");
});

$input.trigger('click');
```

Comment: yup. thats one way. Thanks.

Comment: Use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`.

Comment: Question is about `$input.trigger('click', function(){//code when the click function has been completed})`;

Answer (score 5):

Trigger does not have callback function.

```
.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )
```

**[`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

**What you can do**

```
var $input = $( ".ui-popup-container" ).find( "input" ).eq(2);

$input.on('click',function(){
   console.log("clicked the input");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `bind` or `on` to add callbacks. In your case it should look like this:

```
var $input = $( ".ui-popup-container" ).find( "input" ).eq(2);

function runtests () {
    console.log("clicked the input");
};

$input.bind('click', runtests);
```

Even shorter version for binding click is `$input.click(runtests)`

Then it will be called on click or you can trigger it manually with `$input.trigger('click')` or  simply `$input.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

The Trigger doesn't have a callback function - you can better re-write your code to use the [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$("body").on("click", "#click", function() {
   alert("Clicked!"); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTGZj/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a click handler on every input but want to do something on a specific element:

```
var $container = $(".ui-popup-container"),
    special = 2;

$container.on('click', 'input', function() {
    // do something for every input

    if($(this).index() == special) {
        // your "callback", e.g. the function you want to execute on input:eq2 click
        myfunction();
    }
}).find('input').eq(special).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

`.trigger()` does not accept any callbacks. You don't need it most cases because the bound event handler is immediately executed. However, if you have an AJAX call in trigger event handler, the code from accepted answer will not work:

```
$input.trigger('click');
runtests();
```

You will have to use `setTimeout()` like this:

```
$input.trigger('click');
setTimeout(function () {
    runtests();
}, 250);
```

Or consider using `success` or `error` callbacks for `.ajax()` call in `.trigger()` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Denys Séguret's logic is right. But when needed a callback function after trigger function, $.when is usable:

```
$.when($input.trigger("click"))
 .done(function () { runtests(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
$('#inputTxt1').change(function(e, callback1, data) {

    /*  other statement ...   */  
    
   if(typeof(callback1)==='function'){
       callback1(data);
   } 
});

$('#button2').click(function(e){
    $('#button1').trigger('change', [secondCallback, 'data to callback']);
});

function secondCallback(data){
    var result = data;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on what the code does and how it helps the OP?

Comment: Oops! I misunderstand about question. Actually I just really want to show some nested triggering. Hope this is the gift for someone who are looking for this solution. Im very sorry and thanks for your remind.