# jQuery Trigger not firing without alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, dom-events

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var verifyRefineSearchString = function(element) {
    jQuery('#refine-search-submit').trigger("filter.selection", {FilterType:"Type", FilterValue:"Value"}) ;
    alert();
    element.value = jQuery.trim(element.value);
    if (element.value.length <= 0) {
        alert('Please enter a search term.');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
</script>
```

It fires a trigger if there is an alert.
If I remove the `alert()` it does not fire a trigger.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Maybe a timing issue? When I run into issues like this, I usually have to setup a callback of some sort. Likely the alert is giving the first statement enough time to complete what is needed before the next statement.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites That's correct, that's why it's really interesting to see the handler of `filter.selection` event.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites What sort of callback should I add here ? Please give example. Thank you.

Comment: According to this, you shouldn't need a callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519410/how-to-run-a-callback-function-on-a-jquery-triggerclick  >> If you want to test and see if the delay the alert creates is indeed what is allowing it to work, setup a timer and have your next statements fire when the timer is complete.

Comment: This suggests using load instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246409/callback-for-trigger-function (not sure if this is applicable in your case)

Comment: I looked at the load, but that is not helping either. :(